# can I use `Phoenix` channels in a React App

Tags: reactjs, sockets, channel

Can i import `phoenix` https://www.npmjs.com/package/phoenix  with npm into a react project? Or do i have to use a different npm package like `phoenix-react`.  I'm trying to use channels and sockets from Phoenix in a react Application. I want 2 separate apps, 1 phoenix the other React, and i want to open a socket/channel.

Answer (score 0):

SO... yes you can add 'Phoenix' with npm as a resource in a React project. You are using the phoenix js part.